# Sending property as a reference param to a function in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, function, properties, parameters, ref

I want to do something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *obj1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *obj2;

- (id)init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        [SomeClass someFuncWithParam1:*(self.obj1) param2:*(self.obj2)];
    }
}

@implementation SomeClass
+ (void)someFuncWithParam1:(NSObject **)param1 param2:(NSObject **)param2 {

    //init obj1;
    ...
    //init obj2;
    ...
}
@end
```

I haven't found any example how to pass objective-C properties into a function for initialization. I know that it is possible with usual variables but there are no examples about what to do with properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass an argument by reference in (Objective-)C. What you probably mean is to
pass the *address* of a variable as an argument to the method, so that the method can
set the value of the variable via the pointer.

However, this does not work with properties.
`self.obj1` is just a convenient notation for the method call `[self obj1]`, which returns
the value of the property. And taking the address of a return value is not possible.

What you can do is

- Pass the address of the corresponding instance variables:

  ```
  [SomeClass someFuncWithParam1:&_obj1 param2:&_obj2];
  ```

  The disadvantage is that the property accessor methods are bypassed. That may or may not be
  relevant in your case.
- Pass the address of temporary local variables:

  ```
  NSObject *tmpObj1;
  NSObject *tmpObj2;
  [SomeClass someFuncWithParam1:&tmpObj1 param2:&tmpObj2];
  self.obj1 = tmpObj1;
  self.obj2 = tmpObj2;
  ```

Both solutions are not very nice. Alternatively, you could pass the entire object (`self`) to the helper method, which then initializes both properties.

Or you define a custom class with just the properties `obj1` and `obj2`, and make the helper method *return* an instance of this custom class.