# Swift 2.0 'inout' function parameters and computed properties

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm testing Swift 2.0 beta right now and have found strange behaviour. Here is a sample code:

```
private func someFunc(inout someString: String) {
    print("Inside \'someFunc()\'")

    print(someString)
    someString = "Some another string"
}

private var someAncillaryInt = 42

print(someAncillaryInt)

private var someString: String {
    get {
        print("Inside \'getter\'")
    
        return "Some string"
    }
    set {
        print("Inside \'setter\'")
        someAncillaryInt = 24
    }
}

someFunc(&someString)
print(someAncillaryInt)
```

Output:

> 42
>
> Inside 'getter'
>
> Inside 'someFunc()'
>
> Some string
>
> Inside 'setter'
>
> 24

I don't understand why wasn't *getter* called while printing `someString` inside `someFunc()` and why was it when `someFunc()` got passed with `someString`.

One can assume that I don't understand intricacies of *inout* parameters yet and after being passed as *inout* parameter computed property stops being, em, "computed", but why then was 'setter' called when we set another value to `someString`?

Thanks!

**UPD**: I added answer below.

**UPDATE 18/11/2015**: Apple has updated their [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545) with detailed explanation of how inout params work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your confusion might be caused by choosing `someString` both as the
name of a global variable, and as the name of a parameter of the
`someFunc()` function.

`print(someString)` inside `someFunc()` prints the
value of the (local) function parameter, which is completely unrelated
(and hides) the global `someString` variable.

It becomes easier to understand if you rename the function parameter

```
private func someFunc(inout localString: String) {
    print("Inside \'someFunc()\'")
    print(localString)
    localString = "Some another string"
}
```

which is semantically identical (and therefore produces the same output).

You can think of

```
someFunc(&someString)
```

as the following:

- The value of `someString` is retrieved (using the getter method).
- `someFunc()` is executed, with the local parameter `localString`
  set to the value of `someString`.
- On return from `someFunc()`, `someString` is set (using the
  setter method) to the (possibly changed) value of the local parameter
  `localString`.

More information can be found in https://devforums.apple.com/thread/230567 from the Apple Developer Forum,
for example:

> Given the guarantee of a getter and setter, inout follows naturally:
>   when calling a function with an inout argument, logically it calls the
>   getter on the var/subscript and copies the value into a stack
>   temporary which is guaranteed to have physical addressability.  The
>   physical address of the temporary is passed to the inout argument of
>   the function ... .  The callee does
>   whatever it wants with that memory location (and never knows whether
>   the thing passed in was computed or not).  When the callee returns,
>   the setter is invoked to copy the value back into place.

and

> It also guarantees that the getter/setter of a property passed inout
>   will have its getter and setter called once regardless of what the
>   callee does (this is important if the accessors have side effects or
>   are expensive).

but it is also stated that the temporary copy is avoided if necessary.

Comment: I shouldn't have been thinking about 'inout' parameters as analogous to references in C++. This might have been the source of mine confusion.

Comment: @mesmerizingsnow: I am not that familiar with references in C++. But inout parameters definitely are not the same as "passing the address of a variable" in C or Objective-C, so `someFunc(&someString)` would not be possible in Objective-C if `someString` is declared as a property (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605298/sending-property-as-a-reference-param-to-a-function-in-ios).

Comment: My premise was that 'inout' params would act as references in C++. So if you passed some variable as 'inout' parameter you'll get its actual state whenever you access it. That means, for example, if some separate thread is trying to modify the variable (lets say that synchronisation problems are settled) concurrently you'll always get actual state of the variable. But what I see now is that state is preserved only when variable is passed. That's why 'getter' wasn't called. This logic doesn't contradict with 'inout' definition though.

Comment: @mesmerizingsnow: I have added some extracts from the Apple Developer Forum to the answer, does that clarify your doubts?

Comment: Yes, thanks. However, I'm not so sure what that guys have been talking about. You know, they discuss Swift compiler future implementation regarding 'inout' specifier which I, personally, wouldn't want to know. But I'm certainly glad that what I came up with is being discussed at developer forums and one can track the progress of that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why wasn't getter called while printing someString inside someFunc() and why was it when someFunc() got passed with someString.

`getter` wasn't called while printing `someString` inside `someFunc()` because it had *already* been called. We already have this string as the `someString` parameter internal to `someFunc()`; we don't need to get it again.

Your output reads:

```
Inside 'getter' //<-- that's the getter being called!
Inside 'someFunc()'
Some string
Inside 'setter'
```

Your code runs:

```
someFunc(&someString) //<-- that calls the getter!
```

This has nothing to do, by the way, with `inout`. You'd see the same thing (as far as the `getter` is concerned) if this had been a normal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin R pointed me out on aforesaid [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/230567) and, specifically, comment #16 made by Chris Lattner (Swift's mastermind) which helped me to understand 'inout' behaviour. Thanks man!

Consider this code:

```
private var someString: String {
    get {
        print("Inside getter")

        return "Some string"
    }
    set {
        print("Inside setter")
    }
}

private func someFunc(inout stringArg: String) {
    let funcName = "`someFunc()\'"

    print("Inside " + funcName)

    let someDontMatter0 = 42, someDontMatter1 = 24

    print(stringArg)

    // sets temporary, not the original one. Hence, no calls to setter
    stringArg = "Some other string"
    stringArg = "No matter what string"

    print("These \(someDontMatter0) and \(someDontMatter1)")

    print("Leaving " + funcName)

    // when callee returns, calls the setter with "No matter what
    // string" as a `newValue'
}

// implicitly creates temporary initialised with `someString' value
// getting from `someString's getter.
someFunc(&someString)
```

For someone coming from C++ background it may seem that the output should be something like:

> Inside `someFunc()'
>
> Inside getter
>
> Some string
>
> Inside setter
>
> These 42 and 24
>
> Leaving `someFunc()'

When in fact the output is the following:

> Inside getter
>
> Inside `someFunc()'
>
> Some string
>
> These 42 and 24
>
> Leaving `someFunc()'
>
> Inside setter

Kinda funny, right?

This kind of counterintuitive behaviour for someone with C++ background is a result of more fundamental logic which underpins many facets of Swift. As one may get from Chris's comment the general way Swift compiler deals with *inout* properties is to create **temporary** object on a stack to store the original value there (hence, call the getter).

So, when you manipulate your *inout* parameter you deal with temporary object (with initial value you passed to the function) but not with the original one (for me, personally, it's kinda vague. But OK, one can deal with that). And finally:

> When the callee returns, the setter is invoked to copy the value back into place

So, if one changes the code a bit:

```
private var someString: String {
    get {
        print("Inside getter")

        return "Some string"
    }
    set {
        print("Inside setter")
    }
}

private func someFunc(inout stringArg: String) {
    // before returning calls `someString's setter
}

// calls `someString's getter
someFunc(&someString)
```

the output will be:

> Inside getter
>
> Inside setter

Also, the same goes to stored properties:

```
private func someFunc() {
    var someString = "Some string" {
        willSet {
            print("Inside \'willSet\' with \'newValue\': \(newValue)")
        }
        didSet {
            print("Inside \'didSet\' with \'oldValue\': \(oldValue)")
        }
    }

    func someOtherFunc(inout stringArg: String) {
        print("Inside `someOtherFunc()\'")
    
        stringArg = "First string"
        stringArg = "Second string"
    
        print("Before leaving the function")
    }

    someOtherFunc(&someString)
}

someFunc()
```

Output:

> Inside `someOtherFunc()'
>
> Before leaving the function
>
> Inside 'willSet' with 'newValue': Second string
>
> Inside 'didSet' with 'oldValue': Some string

From Chris's response:

> It also guarantees that the getter/setter of a property passed inout will have its getter and setter called once regardless of what the callee does (this is important if the accessors have side effects or are expensive)

Ok, but what if some method which takes *inout* parameter in some circumstances doesn't modify it (doesn't call the setter or doesn't modify that temporary variable, you name it)? Also, what if I conceived some important logic behind my computed variable's getter and setter and ran into that specific circumstances (just imagine that I open and close files inside getter/setter)? The getter and setter would be called when they had better not.

I'd really like to see the Chris's response in some form in Apple's final Swift 2.0 Programming Guide.