# Custom operator (with inout) triggers NSManagedObject change

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I created a custom operator to change the value only when it's different :

```
func ?!=<T:Equatable> (inout lhs:T?, rhs:T?) {
    if lhs != rhs {
        lhs = rhs
    }
}
```

I used it like that :

```
eventMO.id ?!= eventObject.id
```

In my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`  `controller(_:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)` returns `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move` there should be actually nothing when the value is the same.

I tested with the debugger, and the left hand parameter doesn't get modified in my test case.

So I'm guessing : Does an inout operator trigger a change on a `NSManagedObject` ?

Comment: Managed object properties are computed properties, so this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232190/swift-2-0-inout-function-parameters-and-computed-properties would apply here as well, i.e. the setter is called in any case. See also this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34400794/1187415.

Comment: Hey Matthieu Riegler, have you solved this issue somehow?